# How to tell a C or a C++ compiler that pointers are not aliased

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pointer-aliasing, restrict-qualifier

I have function that receives an array of pointers like so:

```
void foo(int *ptrs[], int num, int size)
{ 
  /* The body is an example only  */
     for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { 
       for (int j = 0; j < num-1; ++j)
         ptrs[num-1][i] += ptrs[j][i];
     }
}
```

What I want to convey to the compiler is that the pointers `ptrs[i]` are not aliases of each other and that the arrays `ptrs[i]` do not overlap. How shall I do this ? My ulterior motive is to encourage automatic vectorization.

Also, is there a way to get the same effect as `__restrict__` on an iterator of a `std::vector` ?

Comment: Important note: The C++ standard does NOT support the `restrict` qualifier from C99 -- its not even a keyword.  So any use of `restrict` in a C++ program is relying on an implementation extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`restrict`, unlike the more common `const`, is a property of the *pointer* rather than the *data pointed to*.  It therefore belongs on the *right* side of the '`*`' declarator-modifier. `[]` in a parameter declaration is another way to write `*`. Putting these things together, you should be able to get the effect you want with this function prototype:

```
void foo(int *restrict *restrict ptrs, int num, int size)
{
   /* body */
}
```

and no need for new names.  (Not tested.  Your mileage may vary.  `restrict` is a pure optimization hint and may not actually do anything constructive with your compiler.)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, one of those "restrict" declarations is superfluous; there are no other "int **"-type variables around with which aliasing could occur. "int * restrict * ptrs" should do the job. And I wonder if "int * restrict ptrs[]" might do it also...

Comment: IMHO both `restrict`s are necessary, since other pointers might otherwise exist outside of the scope of `foo`.

Comment: "What I want to convey to the compiler is that the pointers ... are not aliases of *each other*"

Comment: Also, late comment, but semantics of pointers "outside of the scope of `foo`" are not affected by `restrict` qualifiers on parameters of foo. The second `restrict` is NOT necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
void foo(int *ptrs[], int num, int size)
{ 
  /* The body is an example only  */
     for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { 
       for (int j = 0; j < num-1; ++j) {
         int * restrict a = ptrs[num-1];
         int * restrict b = ptrs[j];
         a[i] += b[i];
     }
}
```

... should do it, I think, in C99. I don't think there's any way in C++, but many C++ compilers also support restrict.

Comment: Ah I see, I have to introduce new names. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can use a similar trick to mark the object reference by an iterator as unaliased (i.e. assign its address to a restricted pointer).

Comment: You've got the '`restrict`' qualifiers on the wrong side of the '`*`'s here.

Comment: @davmac Do you mean something like `__restrict__ ptr = & (*iter)` ? Seems it will work, nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, pointer arguments are assumed not to alias if they point to fundamentally different types ("strict aliasing" rules).

In C99, the "restrict" keyword specifies that a pointer argument does not alias any other pointer argument.

Comment: Pretty sure strict aliasing rules apply in `c` as well as `c++`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: Yes, yes they do.  Also, this answer does not tell the OP anything he or she did not already know.

Comment: The strict aliasing rules are more efficient in C++, because the parameters tend to be `std::vector<int>&` and not `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Call `std::memcpy`. Memcpy's definition will have `restrict` set up if your language/version and compiler support it, and most compilers will lower it into vector instructions if the size of the copied region is small.